# Do celltags have to be strings?

Tags: notebooks, cells

The Wolfram Documentation Center states that CellTags are "usually strings".  I'm confused on what "usually" means.   Is it possible to create one that uses boxes?  For example, can I create a celltag that has the name: $R^3$?

I think the answer is no, but the word "usually" in the documentation center is throwing me off.

Explanation to User 6014:  The celltag doesn't appear in the nice format $R^3$.  See pic below.

[image]

Comment: Why not "$R^3$" :)

Comment: I do not believe it is a string in Mathematica.  Am I wrong?  I tried using the Add/Remove Cell Tags Dialog box.  It does not let me type this in.

Comment: `CellPrint[TextCell["abcd", "Text", CellTags -> "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(R\), \(3\)]\)"]]` seems to work fine for me. Note that this is the input form of the manual "$R^3$"... but calling the cells with tag "$R^3$" calls it without issue

Comment: Yes,  I think I should be able to make this work in my situation as I don't necessarily need the cell tags to look nice.  However, I'm still interested if it's possible.  Can celltags appear in this nice notation?  Or must they appear as you described in input notation?

Comment: Well I had to copy and paste the input form so that it would show up appropriately here. In Mathematica it showed up as $R^3$ as you'd expect.

Comment: I'm not getting this.  See edit above.  The cell tag is in input form.

Comment: Oh.. I was misunderstanding you. I see what you mean now, yes I don't know if it's possible to get linear typesetting there.